# What actually AndroidManifest <queries/> do? Why can I query packageInfo without define <queries/> tag?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-package-managers

I have a packageName list from server's response, And I want to show all applications user installed also in this `packageNameList`. Then I write this piece of code:

```kotlin
fun function() {
  val packageNameList: List<String> = ; // get packageNameList from server's response
  packageNameList.filter { isInstalled(it) }
}

fun isInstalled(packageName:String): Boolean {
  try {
    context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName) != null
  } catch(ignored: Exception) {
    false
  }
}
```

And It works very well on my Xiaomi Mix 4 (MIUI 14.8;Android 13). My App's `targetSdk` is 34. And my AndroidManifest.xml is like this:

```xml
 <manifest>
   <queries> 
      <package android:name="com.tencent.mobileqq" />
      <package android:name="com.tencent.tim" />
      <package android:name="com.tencent.mm" />
   </queries>
 </manifest>
```

only some Chinese chat apps defined.

My question is Why can I query app isInstalled without define all packages in packageNameList to Manifest. What is the  tag do? Do I need some change to my code?
I read Google's doc on this page https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility It said `getPackageInfo()` is limited. but the code execution result seems not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Understanding Package Visibility in Android 11+**

Android 11 onwards introduced package visibility restrictions for privacy and security purposes. Apps targeting API levels 30+ face limitations when using `getPackageInfo()` to query installed apps without explicit permissions or declarations in the manifest.

**Observations and Recommendations:**

Your code's functionality on Xiaomi Mix 4 (Android 13) despite limited queries in the manifest could be attributed to:

1. **Manufacturer-Specific Modifications:** Some manufacturer-specific changes, like MIUI, might relax these restrictions.
2. **App Testing Context:** The behavior might vary, especially between debuggable builds and release builds.

**Recommendations:**

1. **Explicit Declaration of Necessary Packages:** For compatibility across devices and versions, it's advisable to declare all necessary packages in the `<queries>` element, even if they appear to work without it. This promotes clarity and aligns with best practices.
2. **Consider Alternative Approaches:** If checking for specific apps, consider using intent resolution (`PackageManager.resolveActivity`) instead of full package visibility. This approach circumvents the need for broad package queries.
3. **Thorough Testing:** Test your app across diverse devices and Android versions to ensure consistent behavior. This practice helps identify compatibility issues related to package visibility.

Remember, requesting the `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` permission for extensive package querying requires strong justification and approval from Google Play.

---

Comment: You're right, It seems like I already added QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES before and I forgot it. After remove this permission, `fun isInstalled()` is returns false, just like document said.